# How I can convert mbtiles to shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, mbtiles

I downloaded from OpenStreetMap country victor data with (mbtiles) format from this website: [Openmaptiles](https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/planet/)

I need to know how I can convert this file to shapefiles so I can use it in ArcMap.

Comment: Download OSM vector data in .pbf format instead. Vector tiles are meant for visualizing and not to be used as data transfer format.

Comment: Open in QGIS, convert to any format you wish (a geopackage would be an option, IMO), Open in ArcGIS

Answer (score -2):

you can use this online site.this site have many option of format to convert
https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/

Comment: Hi, please take the [tour]. Also, the service you link to does not support the requested conversion.